# why am I only able to see one side data using aggregate function in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Image

[image]

As you all can see the in the image the postImage is showing Array(0), I have used the following code.

```
dbs.collection('posts').aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:{
                from: "images",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "object_id",
                as: "postImage"
            }
        },
    ]).toArray((err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        doc.send(JSON.stringify(res));
        dbs.close();
    })
```

Image of databse:-

post collection

[image]

image collection
[image]

Here posts collections _id matches to the object_id with the images collection.
I want to fetch both the data.
what should I do?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: `$lookup` returns empty array if there are no matching documents in the `from` collection.

Comment: there is the matching document see I have added image to the question.

Comment: `localField: "_id", foreignField: "object_id"` - `_id` has `ObjectId` values and `object_id` has `string` values. To compare and match the field types must be the same.

Comment: can I do it like localField:"_id".valueOf() and then it should work right.

Comment: `ObjectId` has methods to convert to a string value. Or, string to an ObjectId. You can use any of the approaches.